# Reducibility of a variety

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Suppose $X$ is a variety defined in $\mathbb P^n\times\mathbb P^n$ by a divisor.  It projects down to first $\mathbb P^n$ almost every fiber is not $\mathbb P^n$ and assume every fiber is reducible.  Is $X$ is reducible?

Comment: Presumably you want to consider $n  > 1$. (For $n = 1$ the statement clearly fails.)

Answer (score 7):

As Vesselin Dimitrov remarked, this fails for $n=1$. Here is a counterexample for $n=2$: the variety in $\Bbb{A}^2\times\Bbb{A}^2$ with equation 
$$
x_1^2y_1-x_2^2y_2=0
$$
is irreducible; yet, the fibers of the projection to the first factor (obtained by fixing the values of $y_1$ and $y_2$) are all reducible. You can take the projective closure to extend this to $\Bbb{P}^2\times\Bbb{P}^2$.

Comment: Ping? Viktor! I had thought of you... and I don't know where you are... geographically... :)  I had thought you were in luxuriously rural-bucolic Oswego, but their pages don't reflect your presence... I did look around, but could find no better way to say hello than this...